# How to extract diagonal slices from a 3D array in matlab

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

My question might be trivial. I have a large 3D matrix (m by n by k elements) in MatLab and want to extract all diagonal slices and store them in another 3D array. For a better representation, I have attached a picture. the dashed lines are the diagonal slices I am looking for.

[image]

Comment: (row, column, page) is the indexing in matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a `m x n x k` array `a` use the following method to extract the slices into a cell array:

```
idx = repmat(reshape((0 : k - 1), 1, 1,[])+(1 : n), [m, 1, 1]);
result = accumarray(idx(:), a(:), [], @(x){reshape(x, m, 1,[])});
```

The slices have dimensions `[m x 1 x y]` where `y` ranges from `1` to `min(n,k)`.

For old MATLAB versions use the following (`bsxfun` instead of implicit expansion):

```
idx = repmat(bsxfun(@plus, reshape((0 : k - 1), 1, 1,[]), (1 : n)), [m, 1, 1]);
result = accumarray(idx(:), a(:), [], @(x){reshape(x, m, 1,[])});
```

Comment: Dear @rahnema1 with this definition and indexing, `[m,n,k]=size(a)` , I got error in applying your solution.